# Depth path problem while including public folder

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, ejs

Folder path image:-

[image: folder path image:-]

Css file is not working in exercises folder, only importing header-ejs file without styles, but it's working for chapters and other files... How do I fix it?

exercise.ejs codeimage:-

[image: exercise.ejs codeimage:-]

chapters.ejs file:

[image: chapters.ejs file]

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: included code image..#tia

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a public folder, and inside that public folder I had a css folder with my styles.css in it. In my header.ejs, I referred to it as css/styles.css . The header.ejs was in the views/partials folder. Look at the photo.[image: The Files]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"> is my code in header.ejs
```

Comment: same as  done by me, but stylesheet is working fine for home and chapter ejs but not working for exercise  ->this is the problem..